# Computing transforms in a Gazebo plugin

Tags: transforms, gazebo-plugin, tf2

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have a plugin, from which I'd like to modify some link parameters based on the position of the link relative to another link. What's the easiest way to get this information? My normal ROS instinct is to reach for tf2, but then I'm dependent on a bunch of external stuff which I really don't want to be, including robot_state_publisher.

So far, I'm just grabbing the `GetWorldCoGPose` for each link and subtracting. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/9029/computing-transforms-in-a-gazebo-plugin/) by [mikepurvis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1213/mikepurvis/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 67 on 2015-06-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Currently there is not a more elegant way. We are working on a form of tf for Gazebo, but it won't be available until gazebo7.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mikepurvis](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1213/mikepurvis/) on 2015-07-02**:
Okay, cool. So in the short term, subtracting world poses is a reasonable workaround?